# Can you have DTOs as return types of Spring Data 2 methods?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I was reading [Spring Data documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20230929080923/https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) and noticed this example:

```java
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, UUID> {

  Collection<NamesOnly> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

```java
interface NamesOnly {

  String getFirstname();
  String getLastname();
}
```

It should work with DTOs too:

> Another way of defining projections is by using value type DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) that hold properties for the fields that are supposed to be retrieved. These DTO types can be used in exactly the same way projection interfaces are used, except that no proxying happens and no nested projections can be applied.
>
> If the store optimizes the query execution by limiting the fields to be loaded, the fields to be loaded are determined from the parameter names of the constructor that is exposed.

It caught my attention since it can theoretically rid us of at least some of the mappers in our project. However, it couldn't be pulled off right away. An MRE:

```java
public interface CardRepository extends Repository<Card, UUID> {
    List<CardIdDto> findCardIdsByAccountId(UUID accountId);
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "card")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Card {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Account account;
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private CardStatus status;
}
```

```java
public enum CardStatus {
    ACTIVE, NON_ACTIVE
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private List<Card> cards;
}
```

```java
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CardIdDto {
    private UUID id;
}
```

```java
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test") // for additional logs, ddl-auto is disabled too
@Sql(
        executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
        scripts = {"/schema-h2.sql", "/data-h2.sql"}
)
class CardRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private CardRepository cardRepository;
    private final static UUID ACCOUNT_ID = UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1");

    @Test
    void testFindIds() {
        List<CardIdDto> cardIds = cardRepository.findCardIdsByAccountId(ACCOUNT_ID);
        assertThat(cardIds).asList().hasSize(2);
    }
}
```

```sql
-- schema

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.account
(
    id                        UUID           PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.card
(
    id                UUID             PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id        UUID             NOT NULL REFERENCES account (id),
    status            VARCHAR(30)      NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
-- data

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.ACCOUNT
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1');

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CARD
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000c1', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1', 'ACTIVE');

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CARD
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000c2', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1', 'ACTIVE');
```

The exception message is not helpful:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode (org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode and org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

So I am wondering, is the trick possible in Spring Data 2 (we haven't upgraded to 3)